# How to get invitations from the bot from the servers it is on?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command that will be available to me for all invitations to all servers on what is how to do it?

Comment: You need a channel in that guild and you need invite rules so just forget about that. I mean it's possible but the result is in my opinion not worth the work. Also what do you want to do then with the invitations? Join private servers where only friends should be??

Comment: You can create a loop where you get invite links of every server and then add the result into a dictionary with `Key= Server Name and Value= Invite Link`